# Are questions about K-12 (pre-college) education on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Subject line says it all -- I do not recall seeing any questions here about K-12 education here, but I also do not know if there is a better Stack Exchange site for that purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Per the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), only university-level education is within the scope of this site.

> This site is for academics of all levels—from aspiring graduate and professional students to senior researchers—as well as anyone in or interested in research-related or research-adjacent fields.
>
> If you have a question about...
>
> - Life as a graduate student, postdoctoral researcher, university professor
> - Transitioning from undergraduate to graduate researcher
> - Inner workings of research departments
> - Requirements and expectations of academicians
> - **University-level pedagogy**
>
> ... then you're in the right place!

There is a proposal on Area 51 that may be of interest to you: [Primary and Secondary Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/110775/primary-and-secondary-education)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the specific nature of your question(s), you *may* be looking for the [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com) or [CS Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com) sites.

As those site names imply, though, they are about specific subjects, not all of K-12 education, and they tend to be more focused on the problems facing educators as people than issues relating to the field of education broadly.